# binding Static Resource for ContentTemplate

Tags: xaml

How do I use a template dynamically based on a Bound string **(This complains that the Static Resource must be a string, even thought the Binding will return a string)**:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource {Binding Template}}">
    <ContentPresenter />
</ContentControl>
```

So Template is actually just a string that will return which template to use?